# Interpolate JQ variables in make file

Tags: json, bash, shell, makefile, jq

I'm using this command to replace jq variables with shell variables but getting this error

```
jq: error: ami_id_packer/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
```

I'm using this code

```
replace :=  `cat terraform/terraform.tfvars.json | jq -c --arg ami "33" '.ami_id_packer=$ami' ` set_ami:
        @echo $(replace)
```

the same command is working fine when I run it in bash, I'm messing my head around it from a very long time it would be great if someone from the community can help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

i think it means `.ami_id_packer` rather than `ami_id_packer` assume your json looks something like

```
{
"ami_id_packer": ...
}
```

plus since you are in Makefile, $ needs to be escaped, it should be `$$ami`

Comment: thanks a lot, you made my day, can you please help me about how to interpolate variables n make file I have this want to interpolate numeric id

#replace := `cat terraform/terraform.tfvars.json | jq  --arg ami $(NUMERIC_ID) '.ami_id_packer=$$ami'  > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" terraform/terraform.tfvars.json`

Comment: all $ need to be escaped.  like $tmp. and if you can give an example terraform.tfvars.json, it would be much easier for other to show you an working example.